Some styles are not applied when I reload the page in dark mode
In my Next.js application, I have implemented both light and dark modes, with the default theme set to dark mode. However, I've encountered an issue where the button styles are not applied correctly when the server initially loads the page.
The styles only appear correctly after switching between light and dark modes. Additionally, the styles do not persist when the page is reloaded.
I have shared all of my code that I believe is related to this issue. Please let me know where I might be mistaken. Is this a hydration issue? Specifically, when server-side rendering (SSR) sends the HTML, are there situations where some styles are not properly hydrated and might not be applied?
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    screens: {
      mob: "320px",
      tablet: "768px",
      laptop: "1024px",
      desktop: "1280px",
      laptopl: "1440px",
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

// _app.js

import "../styles/globals.css";
import { ThemeProvider } from "next-themes";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="dark" enableSystem={true}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;


// globalstyles.css

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import "./markdown.css";

* {
  font-family: "Hind";
}

body {
  @apply bg-white text-black dark:bg-black dark:text-white;
}

.gradient-circle {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -30px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(40px);
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(248, 107, 223, 1) 0%,
    rgba(107, 107, 248, 0.8) 100%
  );
}
.gradient-circle-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: blur(40px);
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(248, 107, 223, 1) 0%,
    rgba(107, 107, 248, 0.8) 100%
  );
}

.gradient-shadow:hover::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #45caff 0%, #ff1b6b 100%);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 20px, 0) scale(0.95);
  filter: blur(20px);
  opacity: var(0.7);
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

/* 
* Prevents issues when the parent creates a 
* stacking context. (For example, using the transform
* property )
*/
.gradient-shadow:hover::after {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

